# Diffusion-Reaction problem $u_t = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x-y) u(y) dy . u + u^3$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators, linearization

I have bee stuck in this problem since more than a week. During my study I kinda understand how to find the adjoint operator for the linearization. But I have no Idea how to find the linearization to this problem. I have been studying nonlinear dynamical systems and I know how analyze it. But I am new to the diffusion reaction. Any hint or solutions will  help me. Thanks in advance.

Let the equation

$$u_t = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x-y) u(y) dy\right) \cdot u + u^3$$

have stationary solution $S(x)$, where $K(x)$ is sufficiently smooth function and decay exponentially as $|x| \to { \infty}$.

1- Find the linearized operator $L$ w.r.t $S(x)$.

2-Find $L^*$, where $L^*$ is the adjoint operator of $L$, that is,

$$\langle Lf,g \rangle_{L^2} = \langle f ,L^* g\rangle_{L^2}.$$

**Updated**

Let $u(x,t) = S(x) + \varepsilon v(x,t)$, substituting it in the equation, we get

$$\varepsilon v_t = S(x) \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(y) dy + \varepsilon S(x)\int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) v(y) dy  + \varepsilon v(x,t) \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(y) dy + \varepsilon^2 v(x,t) \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) v(y) dy + S^3 (x) + 3 \varepsilon S(x)^2 v(x,t)+ 3 \varepsilon^2S(x) v^2(x,t) + \epsilon^3 v^3(x,t).$$

The terms of order $\varepsilon^0,\varepsilon^2$, and $\varepsilon^3$ are vanishes.

\begin{equation}
    \label{p2eq1}
    v_t =  S(x)\int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) v(y) dy  +   \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(y) dy . v(x,t)+ 3 S(x)^2 v(x,t).
\end{equation}
Then the linearized operator;

$$L_{s} =  S(x)\int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) v(y) dy  +   \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(y) dy . v(x,t)+ 3 S(x)^2 v(x,t).$$

Now we find the adjoint operator.

\begin{align}
    \langle Lf,g \rangle_{L^2} & = \int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(x) f(y) dy  +   \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(y) dy . f(x)+ 3 S(x)^2 f(x)\right) \overline{g(x)} dx.\\
    &= \int_\mathbb{R} \left( \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(x) f(y) dy \right) \overline{g(x)} dx + \int_\mathbb{R} \left(    \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(y) dy . f(x)\right) \overline{g(x)} dx \\
    &+ 3\int_\mathbb{R} \left( S(x)^2 f(x)\right) \overline{g(x)} dx.\\
    &= \int_\mathbb{R} f(y) \left( \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y) S(x) \overline{g(x)} dx \right)  dy +  \int_\mathbb{R}f(x) \left(    \int_\mathbb{R} K(x-y)  S(y) dy. \overline{g(x)}\right)  dx\\
    &+ 3 \int_\mathbb{R}  f(x) \left(S(x)^2 \overline{g(x)} \right)  dx.\\
    &= \int_\mathbb{R} f(y) \overline{\left( \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{K(x-y)} \overline{S(x)} g(x)  dx \right)}  dy +  \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \overline{\left(    \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{K(x-y)} \overline{S(y)} dy . g(x)\right) } dx\\
    &+3 \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \overline{ \left( \overline{S(x)^2} g(x) \right)} dx.\\
\end{align}

Then for $v(x) \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$ we have the adjoint operator $L^*$ of the operator $L$ as;

$$L^*(v(x))= \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{K(x-y)} \overline{S(x)} v(x)  dx + \int_\mathbb{R} \overline{K(x-y)} \overline{S(y)} dy . v(x) + 3 \overline{S(x)^2} v(x).$$

Comment: In order to linearize the problem, substitute $u(x, t) = S(x) + \varepsilon v(x, t)$ in the equation and keep only the terms of order $\varepsilon^1$.

Comment: @Gribouillis could you please help be (like by a comment) what is happening for the integral part?

Comment: The integral becomes $\int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x-y)S(y) d y + \varepsilon \int_{-\infty}^\infty K(x-y) v(y, t) d y$. All this is multiplied by $S(x) + \varepsilon v(x, t)$.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you so much. Honestly, this was clear for me, what I am asking about is the step after this. Since I do not know any information about $K$ except it is decaying fast I can not deal with it as Dirac function?

Comment: The terms of order $\varepsilon^0$ vanish because $S$ is a stationary solution. Also remove the terms in $\varepsilon^2$ and $\varepsilon^3$ and divide everything by $\varepsilon$ to get the linearized equation.

Comment: @Gribouillis Thank you so much. I would like to ask about the second part of the question. Is it similar to this concept?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012460/adjoint-problem-for-convection-diffusion-reaction-equation

Comment: Instead of taking adjoint of a differential operator like that question, you have to do it with integral operators. Concentrate on a small piece like $(Lf)(x) = \int K(x,y) f(y) dy$ and write a candidate adjoint for $L$ also as an integral operator with a slightly different kernel. Then prove that your candidate was correct. Once you do that, you will have an easier time doing $L_S^\dagger$

Comment: @AHusain Thank you so much. I will do it and update my solution ans mention you if you do not mind.

Comment: @AHusain I updated the solution. Could you see it please.

Comment: @Gribouillis Could you please see the updates.